# formatting JSON created by scraping a website with Python and Scrapy

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I scraped a website using Scrapy and Python and managed to save the output into a JSON file with this command:

```
$ scrapy crawl wcr -o top_selling_beans.json -t json
$ cat top_selling_beans.json 
[{"price": "$17.75", "bean_name": "Espresso Torro"},
{"price": "$18.75", "bean_name": "Sulawesi Toarco AA Tana Toraja"},
{"price": "$17.75", "bean_name": "Costa Rica La Minita"},
{"price": "$17.75", "bean_name": "Guatemala Acatenango Finca El Carmen"},
{"price": "$18.25", "bean_name": "Ethiopia Dry-Process Yirga Cheffe Konga"}]
```

My only complaint is that I want "bean_name" to appear before "price".

This is what is in my items.py file:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class WestCoastRoastingItem(Item):
    bean_name = Field()
    price = Field()
```

This is the code for my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from westcoastroasters.items import WestCoastRoastingItem

class WCRSpider(BaseSpider):
  name = "wcr"
  start_urls = ["http://www.westcoastroasting.com"]

  def parse(self, response):
    # Pull out the names and prices for the top sellers
    sel = Selector(response)
    top_sellers = sel.xpath(
      '//div[@id="SideTopSellers"]/div[@class="BlockContent"]/ul/li/div[@class="ProductDetails"]'
    )
    bean_names = top_sellers.xpath('strong/a/text()').extract()
    bean_prices = top_sellers.xpath('div[@class="ProductPriceRating"]/em/text()').extract()

    # Pass data to items
    items = []
    for name, price in zip(bean_names, bean_prices):
      item = WestCoastRoastingItem()
      item['bean_name'] = name
      item['price'] = price
      items.append(item)
    return items
```

Of course, maybe I am being too picky?  Does the order of the key-value pair in a JSON file make any real difference?  If so, how can I have the output look like so:

```
[{ "bean_name": "Espresso Torro", "price": "$17.75"}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order in JSON objects emphatically does not make a difference. Relying on order here is a mistake, you should be using an array if order is important.

You might check out the pprint library if you insist you want to manage order.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, even if you _did_ force an order in the JSON-encoded data, as soon as you imported that data into Python or JavaScript or any other language to do anything with it, you'd end up with a dict/Object/hash/whatever that ignored the order…

Answer (score 1):

Objects are unordered in the JSON format, so the order of the keys makes no difference.

Also, I would advise against outputting JSON. Use JSON-lines (the default format), which outputs a separate JSON-encoded object per line. Having one huge JSON-encoded object will make reading the scraped items inefficient.